# What's different between try_files and rewrite?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

I want to redirect all dynamic request to index.php

for example my `index.php` :

```
<?php
     echo "hi"; 
?>
```

here is my  nginx **configure of php**:

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
```

when i add  configure  with `try_files`:

```
location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/  /index.php =404;
}
```

it just return
**raw text**

```
 <?php echo "hi"; ?>
```

and i modify the nginx configure with `rewrite`  it will return `hi` properly :

```
location / {
         rewrite ^(.*)  /index.php last ;                
 }
```

---

## Question

What's different between  `try_files` and `rewrite` ?

Why the directive `try_files` do not work as i want ?

Comment: Your `try_files` statement is incorrect. It should end with `/index.php` or `=404` **not both**.

Comment: Useful article [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Comment: @Tim thx，it is what i want